# How to configure Friend in LuminusWeb project?

Tags: clojure, authorization, ring

I have a [LuminusWeb](http://www.luminusweb.net/) project running and I want to configure [Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) for authorizing the routes. The trouble with this is that, friend has to be configured with the ring server like so:

```
(def page (handler/site
            (friend/authenticate
            routes
                  ...

;--- elsewhere ---
(compojure/defroutes routes
  (GET "/" req
```

<sup>[copied from github](https://github.com/cemerick/friend-demo/blob/master/src/clj/cemerick/friend_demo/interactive_form.clj#L26)</sup>

But, in [LuminusWeb's handler](https://github.com/PhosphorusGorilla/lumfriend/blob/master/src/lumfriend/handler.clj), the routes are all spread over various places and it has it's own views and models so handler barely has all routes. However, all the scattered routes are declared with the configuration. This is from LuminusWeb:

```
(def app (app-handler
          ;; add your application routes here
          [home-routes app-routes]
          ...
```

As a beginner, my understanding of clojure is limited and I am not sure how to configure `Friend` in this place. I've tried to look at the documentation of Friend, but apart from the [readme](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) and [friend-demo apps](https://github.com/cemerick/friend-demo/blob/master/src/clj/cemerick/friend_demo/) there isn't anything else and all demo apps use the same configuration.

I have setup a very [basic project on github](https://github.com/PhosphorusGorilla/lumfriend) which has just the bare bones of luminusweb and integrated Friend.

I was blindly inserting the configuration of Friend in different (and sensible) places until I got rid of all the compile time errors, but the project still doesn't run for one reason or another (results in run time error).

So, the question is, when my routes are scattered in different namespaces and I don't have a  handler/site method, Where should I configure Friend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing that same question some days ago and I solved it like this.

In my handler.clj file I define my routes like this:

```
(def secured-routes
  [(friend/authenticate user-routes user/friend-settings)
   (friend/authenticate epics-routes user/friend-settings)
   home-routes app-routes])
```

As you can see, some of them are secured and some are not. And then, in the app function I call them like this:

```
(def app
  (app-handler
           ;; add your application routes here
           secured-routes
           ;; instead of [user-routes home-routes ...]
...))
```

**Update**
Yea, exactly, thats how my friend settings look like:

```
(def friend-settings
  {:credential-fn             (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn login-user)
   :workflows                 [(workflows/interactive-form)]
   :login-uri                 "/user/login"
   :unauthorized-redirect-uri "/user/login"
   :default-landing-uri       "/"})
```

where *login-user* is a function that connects to datomic and reads user/password map.

You can have a look at the code at: https://github.com/sveri/friend-ui/
But please be aware, I am a clojure beginner myself and the code there surely is far from being idiomatic or follows best practices.

Comment: Hi sveri, is the `user/friend-settings` above the configuration for friend? something like `{:credentials-fn (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn users)}` will do? Thank to your code, I managed to get rid of the user-identity-nil runtime error, but now it's not letting me sign in at all, even with right password. It just redirects me back to login page with `&login_failed=Y&username=user` added...

Comment: Ah, actually, I had a typo in the configuration.. and interestingly, friend didn't throw an exception, I guess it just ignores unknown keys.. Thank you very much!

Comment: The code seems to be great, I can learn much from there.. Many thanks for sharing it :)

Answer (score 1):

If `app` in your example is a ring handler, then you can pass that into the `friend/authenticate` middleware just like any other ring handler function.  Just be sure to add the Ring middlewares that Friend requires (embodied in `compojure.handler/site`, but which you can add directly if you prefer) after/outside of `friend/authenticate`.

Comment: Thank you. Was trying to create a custom middleware but it wasn't going so well, trying out @sveri's answer now.